# Joomla 3+ Menu Link to Anchor in article which is already a menu item

Tags: menu-item, submenu

I'm looking to solve a problem:

I have a rather long page and want to implement a side menu for quickly linking to specific content areas.

- Plan Your Visit
- - Directions and Parking
- - Accessibility

The two submenu items (Directions/ Parking and Accessibility) are in the Plan your Visit Article and I do have anchor links for these areas.

I'm just unsure how or what is the preferred way of using a joomla menu item to display anchor links in articles.

i tried using the external URL, with full URL to the article with anchor link on the end. This URL works when I put it into the browser but not when I use it in an external URL menu item type.

Any idea how I would accomplish this?

Comment: What attribute do you set to your specific content areas for scrolling to them?

Answer (score 2):

Use **external URL** menu item type for this. You don't have to provide the full URL. Just insert #<your-link-id> into the link field of your menu item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anchors are solved by browser and they are not received server side. Thus, Joomla does not receive anchors.

If your browser does not jump to the anchor, it may be an issue caused by a long page. Browsers only wait a certain amount of time to jump to the anchor (it depends on browser version)

Comment: I realize that, however, it seems that when you put in a joomla menu item it automatically adds it's own pretty url at the end which I believe is messing things up. Actually it just gives me the itemID (http://www.example.com/?Itemid=642). So putting anchors in and linking to them in articles is not an issue for me, it's an issue when I try to link to an anchor from a menu item. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way to define anchors in a menu item is with an external link menu type. You can assign the same link + anchor (index.php?option=com_...&view=....&Itemid=....#test) and Joomla will show the final SEF Url + anchor.

Comment: What are you exactly type in external link menu type?

Comment: You can assign any Url. It will go directly to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this how to add anchor key in joomla from this url (http://www.cloudaccess.net/joomla-knowledgebase/96-joomla-3-1/article-manager/500-adding-anchors-joomla-3-0.html)

Comment: I can add the anchors fine. The anchor links work fine. However, when I use the anchor link in as a menu item, it does not work. Goes to 404 page.